# Multi-query date histogram in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the Elasticsearch date_histogram aggregation for binning/bucketing my data. This works fine when plotting the results of a single query:

```
{
    "query": {...},
    "aggs" : {
        "timeline" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I now want to use ES for binning/bucketing the results of multiple queries. At the end, I need a line chart with each query representing a single line on the chart.

So, is it possible to use a single bucketing for multiple queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, ended up defining a custom range for the date field and executed multiple queries with the same custom range. Probably not the most efficient way, but works fine.

```
{
    "query": {...},
    "aggs" : {
         "ranges" : {
              "date_range" : {
              "field": date,
              "format": yyyyMMdd,
              "ranges": ranges}
         }
    }
}
```